# Save / Load IOS data

Tags: ios, load, save

I've been attempting to get my app to save and load data from a set of arrays in the app, the odd issue is that when the app terminates (completely shut down) the data does not seem to load upon being restarted, i've had a look over a lot of posts, tutorials etc but i can't seem to get it to work, i have two test buttons on the app to trigger the save and load methods and also a button to clear the records, when i use these to test, it works perfectly and the data saves and loads correctly.

My current setup is as follows:

- I have a plist file called data.plist in the supporting files directory, inside this file i have the various arrays with the same data in index 0 as the data that is initialised when the global data class creates an instance of itself.

My save code:

```
- (void)saveData{

    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    // create dictionary with arrays and their corresponding keys
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personalitySliderValue, looksSliderValue, humourSliderValue, chemistrySliderValue, emptySlider, notesValues,nameValues, noValues, ratingValues, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"personality", @"looks", @"humour", @"chemistry",@"empty",@"notes",@"name",@"no",@"rating", nil]];

    NSString *error = nil;
    // create NSData from dictionary
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    // check if plistData exists
    if(plistData)
    {
        // write plistData to our Data.plist file
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
    }

}
```

My load code:

```
- (void)loadData{

    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    // check to see if data.plist exists in documents
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
        // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle CHECK D capitalisation
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    // read property list into memory as an NSData object
    NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSString *errorDesc = nil;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    // convert static property list into dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionaryTemp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (!dictionaryTemp)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
    }
    // assign values
    personalitySliderValue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"personality"]];
    looksSliderValue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"looks"]];
    humourSliderValue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"humour"]];
    chemistrySliderValue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"chemistry"]];
    emptySlider = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"empty"]];
    notesValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"notes"]];
    nameValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"name"]];
    noValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"no"]];
    ratingValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionaryTemp objectForKey:@"rating"]];

}
```

And finally the app delegate methods:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


    // save the app data

    [[GlobalData sharedGlobalData]saveData];
    NSLog(@"save method run");


}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

    // load the app data

    [[GlobalData sharedGlobalData]loadData];
    NSLog(@"load method run");
}
```

This has literally been making me pull my hair out, so any help would be great!

Comment: As user1885297 said, load it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. That way you're confident it gets loaded before the user interface is presented. As an aside, you can simplify your code if you excised references to `NSData` altogether, and just saved using the `NSDictionary` instance method `writeToFile` and loaded using the class method `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`.

Comment: Thanks Rob i'll probably make said changes too, i had so much difficulty getting this to work properly that i ended up using a tutorial that is probably a little outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load data at launch time in this app delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   ....
   [[GlobalData sharedGlobalData] loadData];
}
```